# Customize strikethrough in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

When you apply strikethrough or underline to text in Illustrator you can't define the color or weight of that line. Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe using an effect and saving that as a style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a new fill via the **Appearance Panel**
- Set the Fill color to whatever color you want your strikethrough/underline to be
- Highlight this new fill in the **Appearance Panel**
- Choose `Effect > Convert To Shape > Rectangle` from the menu
- Tick the **Absolute** option and enter the height and width you want the rule/line

[image]

- Add `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to move the rule/line to some other position in relation to the text

[image]

Remember, when you're done doing this once, you can drag the text to the **Graphic Styles** panel. That way, in the future, you simply need to click the style to apply your custom strikethrough/underline.

(This is how it was done before Adobe added the underline/strikethrough options to Illustrator.)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for such a complete answer! I couldn't find this anywhere, there had to be way.